# Can an "ascx" user control wrap content?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to create an ascx control that can wrap content like a panel.  I'm looking to do something like -

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FOO" TagName="Section" Src="CollapsibleSection.ascx" %>
    <Foo:Section runat="server">
        [ Section of asp.net webforms page ]
    </Foo:Section>
```

It has been a while since I've done web forms and cannot remember if this is possible to do?  While I could write a fully custom control, there are many advantages in my app if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referred to as a templated control.

Here's a simple tutorial explaining how this is done in both C# and VB.Net:  [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)

Quoted from MSDN (link above):

> 1. In the .ascx file, add an ASP.NET PlaceHolder control where you want the template to appear.
> 2. In the user control's code, implement a property of type ITemplate.
> 3. Define a server control class that implements the INamingContainer interface as a container in which to create an instance of the
>      template. This is called the template's naming container.
> 4. Apply the TemplateContainerAttribute to the property that implements ITemplate and pass the type of the template's naming
>      container as the argument to the attribute's constructor.
> 5. In the control's Init method, repeat the following steps one or more times:
>
>    - Create an instance of the naming container class.
>    - Create an instance of the template in the naming container.
>    - Add the naming container instance to the Controls property of the PlaceHolder server control.

Answer (score 6):

You need to decorate your user control with [`TemplateContainerAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontainerattribute.aspx) and inherit from [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx).